# Is a straight line considered a wave?

Tags: trigonometry, definition

Is a straight line considered a wave? When a sine wave's (or another wave's) amplitude is zero, is it still considered a wave mathematically?

In other words: given $f(x) = a\sin(x)$, when $a = 0$, is $f(x)$ still considered a sine function?

Comment: Depends who you ask.  I don't know that there's a universal definition of a "wave" in this context.

Comment: If your definition of a wave is "a function satisfying the equation $f''+a^2f=0$", then, obviously, yes, a zero function is a wave.

Comment: A slight generalisation of @TZakrevskiy's point: there is a partial differential equation known fairly ubiquitously as "the wave equation", and (at least some classes of) straight lines do satisfy this equation.

Comment: Yes... and no. You can't assign a unique frequency nor a phase to such a signal.